# more performant to have normalized or denormalized tables

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, performance, normalization

I am currently developing an mvc application to read from an existing sql server database. The database is denormalized - and I was looking at modifying some tables to normalize it to a degree.

This led to a discussion with a fellow developer as the most preformant way to read the data, or if the structure should change or not. The data will be read via ado.net with a stored procedure. Question I have is, is it more performant to have numerous fields in a table (denormalized) OR have several tables with inner joins (normalized) to retrieve the data?

I should have mentioned, the actions on the tables will be 95% read, 5% write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your should use denormalized data for data analysis purposes, intensive reporting usage. For the mentioned purposes having a denormalized will contribute to improve performance.

Without having much knowledge about the application you are going to implement, for a 'standard' client-server application, where you are supposed to work with a DOM plenty of classes and read & write data constantly, I would go vote for normalizing the data and avoid as much as possible maintaining duplicated data. Try to simplify the design the of the tables so that they 'feel comfortable' with your domain model.

So, briefly, normalized more performant for intensive data read, denormalized more performant (and more comprehensive) for intensive read & write of domain object model classes.

Comment: the actions on the tables will be 95% read, 5% write, so better to normalize?

Comment: If that 95% is to be spent on reports, that would cost hundreds of JOINs on denormalized data, then I would recommend you, yes, keep the data normalized.

Comment: The reads is for a real time system that displays data to the end user. I am slightly unclear, is your suggestion to split the data in to multiple tables or keep it all in one (avoiding joins)?

Comment: Yes, avoid joins in such case. Just FYI, in my case, we have already in production an application that almost 95% or even more, is static data, but we need the best performance and most concurrency as possible for r/w operations in the rest of the data 5%, so we keep our table structure denormalized. The problem is that we suffer from time to time performance problems when the people execute complex queries.

Comment: But what I commented just above refers to our concrete scenario, my client does not make money with reports, makes money when more customers can be satisfied at the same time so we gave priority guaranteeing high concurrency in r/w operations.

Comment: Ok - so for my situation for real time read data (95%), I try to stay away from joins and have one big table, a denormalized approach. Thanks for the help working this out.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it de-normalised for a reporting application.

As long as the de-normalised structures fit your needs, it will be faster.

If it's being populated from a normalised database(s), all is good. Even if it wasn't I still wouldn't normalise this database, I'd create a normalised version for data collection and then use that to populate your current structure.

The design compromises you have to make to do collection and reporting from one database, don't take long to cost a lot more than another database server and some sort of transfer manouever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be reading more than writing, denormalization is a good idea.

If you will be writing more than reading, you should normalize your tables.

If you are not sure, or will have a blend of both, try benchmarking or load testing with both configurations, and see which works better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

To  retrieve the data  denormalized  is good choice because less no of joins  , storage  is cheaper than performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is primarily about elimination of duplication, for ease of maintenance and minimization of storage required.

Denormalization is primarily done to improve the performance of specific queries, but because some data is duplicated (usually key data) it does make maintenance a touch trickier, and increases storage requirements.